# HTML5 <section>'s inside <article> and header

Tags: html, structure, semantics, article

I'm trying to make a semantic HTML5 code and not sure if it will be right.
Visualy I have an article/post divided in 3 cols:

**IMAGE** (200px) | **H1+ Summary + More Link** (350px) | **Additional Section with 2 headers H2**  (150px)

In CSS I'll **float:left** - *figure, .post-summary, .post-aside*.

Here is Ver.1:

```
<article>
        <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/temp/entry_01.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>Title for Case Study</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <div class="post-summary">          
            <section>
                <h1>MAIN Article Title</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
                <a href="#">read more</a>
            </section>              
        </div>

        <div class="post-aside">
            <section>
                <h2>The Charges:</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>The Verdict:</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </section>
        </div>
</article>
```

Ver. 2

```
<article>
        <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/temp/entry_01.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>Title for Case Study</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <section class="post-summary">
            <h1>MAIN Article Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <a href="#">read more</a>
        </section>                          

        <section class="post-aside">
            <h2>The Charges:</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum text ...</p>

            <h2>The Verdict:</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum text...</p>
        </section>

</article>
```

Which one is right?

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what you want..

> div — the "generic flow container" we all know and love. It’s a
>   block-level element with no additional semantic meaning.
>
> section — a "generic document or application section". A section
>   normally has a heading (title) and maybe a footer too. It’s a chunk of
>   related content, like a subsection of a long article, a major part of
>   the page (eg the news section on the homepage), or a page in a
>   webapp’s tabbed interface.

http://boblet.tumblr.com/post/130610820/html5-structure1
[Link to article](http://boblet.tumblr.com/post/130610820/html5-structure1)

I would use it this way (***your v2***):

```
<div> <!-- Main article div -->
    <article> <!-- First article -->
        <section><!-- Header, about the author... --></section> 
        <section><!-- related info .. --></section> 
        <section><!-- conclusion --></section> 
    </article>

    <article>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
        <section></section>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I thougth that `<h1>` should be as first-level in DOM of `<article>` to be the most important Header of this article

Comment: It's just a mocup. Didn't see any question about the relevance of header tags.

Comment: :) bc I wanted to ask, but forgot. Sry

Comment: In HTML there is a saying that order should NEVER be skipped. <h1></h1> <h2></h2> <h3></h3>. But in HTML5 the first header element is set as the article header. Regardless of the header level.

Comment: in HTML4 I knew it, but in html5 didn't. Thanks for help

Comment: I'd use a header tag instead of a section for the header, about the author part.

Comment: The header goes inside the section tag.

Answer (score -21):

That's not right... both of them, and the answer too... DON'T USE DIV ! USE SECTION INSTEAD !

Comment: Why not use div? Every component of the HTML is allowed. It's up to the developer to figure out, what component is the correct to use. You can create a list with out using the list attribute - But you should use the list if you can. It's the same with divs, sections and articles.